# Saving an image file with Node.js request library causes exception

Tags: image, node.js, stream, request

This is from the **request's** Github repo - https://github.com/mikeal/request

*You can stream any response to a file stream.*

```
request('http://google.com/doodle.png').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('doodle.png'))
```

I have modified it like so, where largeImage is a absolute url path from 3rd-party website.

```
request(largeImage).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./img/large/demo.jpg'));
```

But I get the following error (not sure why?). I have looked at the **createWriteStream** API and it seems to be correct. If I only include "demo.jpg" it works fine. But if I include path next to "demo.jpg" it throws an exception.

```
stream.js:81
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
            ^
Error: ENOENT, open './img/large/demo.jpg'
10 Oct 16:51:02 - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

**UPDATE:** The problem was I didn't include **./public/** folder before the **/img/**.

This updated code works correctly:

```
 request(largeImage).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./public/img/large/demo.jpg'));
```

Comment: most people forgot './public/' including me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all looks OK. My guess is that the issue is related to permissions or maybe needing to create the ./img/large directory first.

Do something like this to get more info:

```
var ws = fs.createWriteStream('./img/large/demo.jpg');
ws.on('error', function(err) { console.log(err); });
request(largeImage).pipe(ws);
```